# convert a list of list into a list of list of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, nested-lists

I have a list of list consist of:

```
> [['Di/in/QUE', 'mana/wh/QUE', 'lokasi/nn/INTENT', 'laboratorium/nnp/LOC', 'dasar/nnp/LOC', '?/?/O'], ['Di/in/QUE', 'mana/wh/QUE', 'lokasi/nn/INTENT', 'laboratorium/nnp/LOC', 'dasar/nnp/LOC', '2/nnp/LOC', '?/?/O'], ['Di/in/QUE', 'mana/wh/QUE', 'lokasi/nn/INTENT', 'laboratorium/nnp/LOC', 'lanjut/nnp/LOC', '?/?/O']]
```

I want to convert it into a list of list of tuple, like this:

```
> [[('Di','in','QUE'), ('mana','wh','QUE'), ('lokasi','nn','INTENT'), ('laboratorium','nnp','LOC'), ('dasar','nnp','LOC'), ('?','?','O')], [('Di','in','QUE'), ('mana','wh','QUE'), ('lokasi','nn','INTENT'), ('laboratorium','nnp','LOC'), ('dasar','nnp','LOC'), ('2','nnp','LOC'), ('?','?','O')], [('Di','in','QUE'), ('mana','wh','QUE'), ('lokasi','nn','INTENT'), ('laboratorium','nnp','LOC'), ('lanjut','nnp','LOC'), ('?','?','O')]]
```

I read the data from a text file so this is my code:

```
with open("corpusposner.txt", "r") as f: 
    vallist = [line.split() for line in f]
f.close()
standard_form_tokens = []
for sentence in vallist:
    for satupsg in sentence:
        anotasi = satupsg.split('/')
        kata, tag, ner = anotasi[0], anotasi[1], anotasi[2]

        standard_form_tokens.append((kata, tag.lower(), ner))
```

When I print standard_form_tokens it return only just one big list of tuple

> [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O'), ('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('2', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O'), ('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('lanjut', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')]

I tried to append the standard_form_tokens into a new list but it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **`tuple`** with **`split`** and a list comprehension:

```
[[tuple(i.split('/')) for i in j] for j in arr]
```

Output:

```
[[('Di', 'in', 'QUE'),
  ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'),
  ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'),
  ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('?', '?', 'O')],
 [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'),
  ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'),
  ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'),
  ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('2', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('?', '?', 'O')],
 [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'),
  ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'),
  ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'),
  ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('lanjut', 'nnp', 'LOC'),
  ('?', '?', 'O')]]
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Never thought that we can use list comprehension like this.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you have only one big list of tuple is that you use two 'for loop' to loop through the list of list but you only append one time at each instance.

Just correct based on your code. You can create an empty temp list, append on it, and then append the temp into your result. Your result then will be a list of lists with tuples inside.

Try this:

```
standard_form_tokens = []
for sentence in vallist:
    temp=[]
    for satupsg in sentence:
        anotasi = satupsg.split('/')
        kata, tag, ner = anotasi
        temp.append((kata, tag.lower(), ner))
    standard_form_tokens.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
[[('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), 
('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')], 
[('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), 
('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('2', 'nnp', 
'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')], [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), 
('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('lanjut', 
'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')]]
```

Comment: I have tried it before using a temporary list but initialize the temp outside first for loop, maybe because of that it still appending into one big list.

Comment: @Irfan HP, you are right, and remember to append every temp (small list) into the big list to make it lists inside list. Which is what standard_form_tokens.append(temp) do.

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
d = [['Di/in/QUE', 'mana/wh/QUE', 'lokasi/nn/INTENT', 'laboratorium/nnp/LOC', 'dasar/nnp/LOC', '?/?/O'], ['Di/in/QUE', 'mana/wh/QUE', 'lokasi/nn/INTENT', 'laboratorium/nnp/LOC', 'dasar/nnp/LOC', '2/nnp/LOC', '?/?/O'], ['Di/in/QUE', 'mana/wh/QUE', 'lokasi/nn/INTENT', 'laboratorium/nnp/LOC', 'lanjut/nnp/LOC', '?/?/O']]

print( [[tuple(j.split("/")) for j in i] for i in d] )
```

**Output:**

```
[[('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')], [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('2', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')], [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('lanjut', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
standard_form_tokens = []
for sentence in vallist:
    standard_form_tokens.append([])
    for satupsg in sentence:
        anotasi = satupsg.split('/')
        kata, tag, ner = anotasi[0], anotasi[1], anotasi[2]
        standard_form_tokens[-1].append((kata, tag.lower(), ner))
```

Comment: `kata, tag, ner = anotasi[0], anotasi[1], anotasi[2]` == `kata, tag, ner = anotasi`

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`:

1.

`map`+list comprehension:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: [tuple(i.split('/')) for i in x],l)))
```

2.

`map`+`map`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: tuple(y.split('/')),x)),l)))
```

Both of them output:

```
[[('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')], [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('dasar', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('2', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')], [('Di', 'in', 'QUE'), ('mana', 'wh', 'QUE'), ('lokasi', 'nn', 'INTENT'), ('laboratorium', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('lanjut', 'nnp', 'LOC'), ('?', '?', 'O')]]
```